# Как несколько раз изменять текст?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textview, android-button

Первый активити

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text1 = "первый текст";
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("result1", text1.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text2 = "Второй текст";
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("result2", text2.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Второй активити

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("result1"));
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("result2"));//Как мне добавить второй getIntent для второй кнопки?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чем проблема сделать так:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text1 = "первый текст";
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", text1.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text2 = "Второй текст";
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", text2.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

---

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("result"));
```